# wit.ai doesn't work well when extracting information from long messages

Tags: bots, wit.ai

I'm trying to train my wit.ai app to extract messages sent with this pattern:

post this whole message minus the 'post' keyword should be extracted

It works fine for a few sentences, but once you start typing out 5 sentences or more, it doesn't seem to recognize anything.

Is this happening to anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah,it does't allow 5 more sentences,but u can click more (bot send) button again like if you have 10 sentences,u can seperate 5 sentences each.Hope this helps
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yup that helped, but eventually I ended up mixing some traditional code with wit.ai API calls for the longer user messages. I'll mark this as an answer either way.